# Error 500 al insertar código PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, error500

He creado una conexión a una base de datos **postgreSQL** mediante el siguiente código:

```
<?php
$dsn = "pgsql:host=localhost; dbname=login_ide; port=5432";
$opt = [
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE               => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
  PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES      => false
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'postgres', 'xxxxx', $opt);

echo "Connected to Database";
?>
```

Y todo parece funcionar correctamente. Sin embargo, cuando añado el siguiente código para consultar la base de datos,

```
<?php
$result = $pdo -> query("SELECT * FROM users");
if ($result -> rowCount()>0) {
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo $row['nombre'];
    }
} else {
    echo "No hay usuarios en la tabla"
}
?>
```

El explorador me devuelve este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Dónde está el fallo?

Comment: Verifica el log de errores. Si el código está así, hay un error de sintaxis, falta el `;` en el último `echo`. Por otro lado, [no se recomienda usar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=pdo+rowcount) `rowCount()` en un `SELECT` y PDO. La documentación dice que hagas un [doble SELECT](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php), uno con `COUNT(*)` y el otro con todas las columnas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No creo que tu conexión esté bien hecha, ya que solo imprimes un `echo "Connected to Database";` pero no validas si se hizo o no la conexión a la BD

Prueba de esta forma:

**ARCHIVO CONEXION.PHP**

```
<?php

class PGSQL{
    var $pdo;
    public function __construct() {
    $host="localhost";
    $dbname="login_ide";
        try 
        {
            $this->pdo = new PDO ("pgsql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname","postgres", "xxxxx");
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            echo "CONEXION ESTABLECIDA";
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            echo 'ERROR AL CONECTAR: '.$e->getMessage();
        }
    }  
} 
?>
```

**Para hacer la consulta:**

```
<?php
#ARCHIVO DE CONEXION
include_once "conexion.php";

#CLASE CON FUNCIONES PARA CONSULTAS
class Test extends PGSQL{
    
    #FUNCION QUE CONSULTA USUARIOS
    public function getUsers(){
        $query = $this->pdo->query("SELECT * FROM users");

        while($registro = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            echo '<br>'.$registro["nombre"];
        }
    }

    public function otraFuncion(){
    }
}

$users = new Test();
echo $users->getUsers();
?>
```

Comment: Efectivamente, parece que la conexión no está bien hecha. Con el código que propones, obtengo el siguiente mensaje: `setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); } catch (Exception $e) { echo "Ocurrió un error con la base de datos: " . $e->getMessage(); } ?>`    ¿Da esto una idea de cuál puede ser el problema? Porque los parámetros son correctos (tengo hecha la misma conexión desde QGIS y funciona correctamente).

Comment: Una disculpa, ya te actualicé la consulta. Lo acabo de probar yo mismo. debe funcionarte